# Referencing to Appendix with page number

Tags: cross-referencing

I can't seem to find a way to use `\ref` to a label and get both the appendix in which it is found and the page number. I would want it to look something like this:

`\ref{foo}` --> `(Appendix B, p. 56)`

Is that even possible?

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: `cleveref` is a good friend for this, the reference format can be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}



\newcommand{\combref}[1]{%
  {%
    \crefformat{page}{p. ##2##1##3}%
    (\Cref{#1},\cpageref{#1})%
    \crefformat{page}{page ##2##1##3}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\section{Main section}

\combref{foo} and \cpageref{foo}

\section{Other section}

\appendix

\clearpage


\section{A section} \label{foo}
\subsection{Another section} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Now if I then want to reference more than one label - is there a way to loose the "page" so that it just writes: page 46, 67, 92?

Comment: @Fireburn6 `\cpageref{...}` works not precisely that way with multiple pages, as far as I know -- but it's another question then.